# struts2バージョンアップ((2.3.16.3→2.3.35))に関して問題、ぜひ助けてください！！！

Tags: struts

始めまして、よろしくお願いいたします。
struts2のバージョンアップ(2.3.16.3→2.3.35)に関する質問ですが、有識の方はぜひ助けてください。
よろしくお願いいたします。

現在jarファイルを差し替えて、実行時にjboss側に下記ようなメッセージが出てきました。

```
JBWEB000236: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception: tag 'select', field 'list', name 'xxxx.xxxxTiming': The requested list key '#_AAA_list' could not be resolved as a collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator type. Example: people or people.{name} - [unknown location]
```

#### 該当のソースコード(jsp)

```
<td width="60%"> 　　
<s:set var="_AAA_list" value="%{#{}}"/>     
<s:iterator value="#xxx.xxxList" var="item">    
<s:set var="BBBValue" value="#item.value" />
<% java.lang.String BBBValue = 
(java.lang.String)pageContext.getAttribute("BBBValue"); %>  
<%if (XXXXX.checkXXX(request, "/xxx/xxx/xxx/dummy_" + BBBValue)) {%>    
<s:if test="#item.value == \"x\" || #item.value == \"y\""> 
<s:set var="_AAA_list" value="%{#_AAA_list.put(#BBBValue, #item.name),
 #_AAA_list}" />    
</s:if>     
<%}%>   
</s:iterator> 
<s:select name="xxxx.xxxxTiming" list="#_AAA_list" 
value="#xxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxx" />           
<s:fielderror fieldName="xxx.xxxx" /> 
</td>
```

#### 試したこと

いろいろ調べまして、`<s:select`を表示時に、`#_AAA_list`がnullに原因と判明しました。
デバッグで、`item.value`、`item.name`の値もちゃんと取れています、
ネックは`value="%{#_AAA_list.put(#BBBValue, #item.name), #_AAA_list}"`で、うまく行けなく、`#_AAA_list`がnullになる原因です。

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

バージョンアップするため、ognl-3.0.6.jarもognl-3.0.21.jarにアップしました。

上記のコードはstrutsの2.3.16.3にうまく行けますが、2.3.35にうまく行けません。

Comment: `<s:set var="_AAA_list" value="%{#_AAA_list.put(#BBBValue, #item.name),
 #_AAA_list}" /> `を実行することで、`_AAA_list`が`null`になったということですか？

Comment: コメントしていただいて、誠にありがとうございました。ご認識の通りです。
固定値として、下記で
<s:select name="xxxx.xxxxTiming" list="#@java.util.LinkedHashMap@{'c':'C','d':'D'}" value="#xxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxx" />  
、行けますが
<s:select name="xxxx.xxxxTiming" list="{'c':'C','d':'D'}" value="#xxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxx" />  
でも行けませんでした。
ognlのバージョンアップ(3.06⇒3.0.21)で、型は明記しないと駄目か？？？

<s:set var="_AAA_list" value="%{#_AAA_list.put(#BBBValue, #item.name),#_AAA_list}" /> 
から
<s:set var="_AAA_list" value="%{#@java.util.LinkedHashMap@#_AAA_list.put(#BBBValue, #item.name),#_AAA_list}" /> 
に修正しても、うまく行けません。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: jarファイルを変えることで、事象が再現するかどうかが変わるなら、OGNLのアップグレードの問題なのかStrtusのアップグレードの問題なのかも切り分けられますよね。さらに、どのバージョンでそれが発生するかまでは絞り込めそうですね。そこまで分かれば、原因の特定はしやすそうですが。

Answer (score 1):

下記のように改修し、解決しました。いろいろありがとうございました。

```
<s:set var="_AAA_list" value="%{#{}}"/>
```

を

```
<s:set var="_AAA_list" 
value="#@java.util.LinkedHashMap@{}"/>
```

に修正し、

```
<s:set var="_AAA_list" value="%{#_AAA_list.put(#BBBValue, #item.name),
 #_AAA_list}" />
```

を

```
<s:set value="#_AAA_list.put(#BBBValue, #item.label)" />
```

に修正して 、うまく行けました。